# javafxports - android screen jumping up when virtual keyboard shown

Tags: android, javafxports

I am using javafxports (in eclipse) and have a simple login screen. If I open the application when the phone is in landscape mode the the screen displays correctly and the virtual keyboard covers the buttons in the lower portion of the screen leaving the user name and password text fields visible. I can rotate the phone and the display is correct in both orientations.

However, if I have the phone in portrait orientation when the app is launched it displays correctly in portrait, but now when I rotate to landscape mode the screen jumps up leaving the buttons visible but pushing the text fields off the top of the screen.

I have tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` (which should do the correct thing according to the docs), `"adjustResize"` and `"adjustUnspecified"` in the manifest but all settings behave the same.

I know people often open an app in portrait but rotate to landscape when required to use the keyboard, so this behavior is not desirable.

Has anyone out there found a work around?